# Azure Cloud Service: “Requested registry access is not allowed"

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I've been trying to deploy a new cloud service (web role) to Azure. It works without issues on my local machine.
But when I deploy the service status is always **Busy**

Using IntelliTrace logs I've found that it keeps trying to read a "Security" registry key which does not exist, and which the ASP.NET process does not have right to create. This is not related to my code and the closest I've come to a solution is [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961463/azure-cloud-service-requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed-vs2015) which suggest to use .NET 4.5.1.

> Due to other Azure dependencies I can not downgrade from .NET 4.5.2 to 4.5.1
>
> **Question:** How do I create this registry key? or make the web role stop trying to access it?

This is a small snippet of the exception that prevents my process from starting:

```
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Opening "Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0". Trying to open the registry key "Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0".   1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Opened "". Tried to open registry key "".  If the attempt failed, null was returned.  To determine which key was accessed, see the previous diagnostic event in this thread.    1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Closed "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Key Management Service". Closed Registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Key Management Service".  1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 

Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Opening "Security". Trying to open the registry key "Security". 1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary ("Requested registry access is not allowed."). Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary ("Requested registry access is not allowed.")   1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Exception: Exception caught: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in System.dll ("Requested registry access is not allowed."). Exception caught: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in System.dll ("Requested registry access is not allowed.")   1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 

Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Opening "System". Trying to open the registry key "System". 1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name> 
Activated   Event   Event Time (UTC+00:00)  Thread
  Registry: Opened "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System". Tried to open registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\System".  If the attempt failed, null was returned.  To determine which key was accessed, see the previous diagnostic event in this thread.    1/9/2018 6:07:11 AM [2672] <No Name>
```

Comment: If there is some demo code could reproduce this issue would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately it would be almost impossible to separate it from its dependencies on other projects. I have another old webjob which has the same dependencies which runs without any issues.